# android editText disable autocorrection

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocorrect

Is it possible to have an editText with suggestions ON but autocorrection OFF ? I've tried:

```
android:inputType="textFilter"

android:inputType="textFilter|textNoSuggestions"
```

but these line of code disable suggestions. So how can I disable only autocorrection?

Comment: try it on a device, because emulator isnt reliable.

Comment: I've tried on two devices, one with ICS and one with android 2.2

Answer (score 1):

There is a deprecated method:

```
android:autoText="false"
```

check if this does the job for you.

Comment: this only disables suggestions.. I nee dto show suggestion but prevent autocorrection

Comment: @gabi changed my answer plz check

Comment: I've tried but it still correct my text (for exa mple, "gor" is corrected to "for). And by default, on a editText, autoText is set to false.